# eval-expression that shows the current character

Tags: elisp, message

What is the correct eval expression which shows the current character in the message area?

I tried the following but they don't work.

```
(message (char-after))
(message '(char-after))
(message 'char-after)
(message char-after)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert the result of `(char-after)` to `string`:

```
(message (string (char-after)))
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `(message "%c" (char-after))`.